# I can't find the url of upwork RSS Feed

Tags: automation, rss, rss-reader

I need to extract data from a search on upwork. I perform the search, download the rss.rss file, then it returns the data I need.

I thought that by copying the url that appears inside the file, `https://www.upwork.com/ab/feed/jobs/rss?api_params=1&amp;orgUid=1644722183543750657&amp;paging=0%3B50&amp;q=power%20bi&amp;securityToken =6d3da4fea63e46335809b04b969c387dd9c266587e9bb01cf56f42d0601b8863e49126a88736c1919ff0cee432bdcd0c9c32fa5f42b8f97e92f370b3ae2612af&amp;sort =recency&amp;userUid=1644722183543750656&amp;verified_payment_only=1`, this would give me the data I am looking for but when I use this url to import the feed I extract other data.

What mistake would I be making and where could I find the url I'm looking for?